# Few problems with my animations c#

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, while-loop

I was working on a winforms app that is animation-heavy, I made all the animations my self.
I use an enum, that contains all animations which is used to call a new thread that runs the appropriate animation for the appropriate control. Here's one example:

```
    private void animateBackColor(Control control)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i <= 255)
        {
            control.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(i, control.BackColor);
            i += 15;
            Thread.Sleep(15);
        }
    }
```

The problems are the following:

+Sometimes, the animations get too stuttery and laggy and they become horrible.

+The controls that are overlapped by the moving ones take too long to repaint which looks ugly.

+I get this bug very rarely "collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated" in the portion that changes a property about the control.

There's also a problem about this animation that fades in an image:

```
    private void animateFadeOut(Control control)
    {
        int i = 255;
        while (i > 15)
        {
            control.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(i, control.BackColor);
            i -= 30;
            Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
        PNL_runningDownloads.Controls.Remove(control);
    }

    public static Bitmap ChangeOpacity(Image img, float opacityvalue)
    {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height); // Determining Width and Height of Source Image
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            ColorMatrix colormatrix = new ColorMatrix {Matrix33 = opacityvalue};
            ImageAttributes imgAttribute = new ImageAttributes();
            imgAttribute.SetColorMatrix(colormatrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
            graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height,
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgAttribute);
        graphics.Dispose(); // Releasing all resource used by graphics 
        return bmp;
    }
```

+It says that the control is currently in use elsewhere
Thank you very much :)

Comment: this kind of animation should require the `Control` to be `DoubleBuffered`, have you tried it yet? About the `control is currently in use elsewhere`, do you have any other thread running and using the control? try placing a `Thread.Sleep()` before `Controls.Remove()` and see if it solves this problem?

Comment: Are your animations long running or they are simple, 1-2s transitions?

Comment: @SOReader most of them last less than 2s

Comment: @KingKing All the controls are double buffered but that doesn't solve anything, also, I don't see where control.remove() can be implemented

Comment: `Sometimes, the animations get too stuttery and laggy and they become horrible` - winforms doesn't  support animations. If you need something that is not horrible, and does not require horrible code, use WPF.

Comment: @HighCore `WPF` is better than `Winforms` in many many aspects, the only one I can find in Winforms, which is better than in `WPF` is the learning curve and how easy you can make familiar with. Maybe because of difficulty, `WPF` is still not very prevalent (although it has been tagged nearly twice more than `winforms`, but that may be it's too problematic with new programmers)

Comment: @KingKing winforms is "easier" to learn because it has much less features (zero in my opinion). BTW that is true only if you have been previously exposed to winforms. If you have never touched any winforms (as I have), then WPF becomes much more self-evident. Having less features means you have less things to learn, but if we're going to consider that as a good thing, then turn off the PC. Having the PC off requires less learning that turning it on and using it.

Comment: @KingKing Of course, the features available when the computer is on `just might` not be available when the machine is off... right? but hey!, it's less learning!

Comment: @HighCore I was comparing `WPF` and `Winforms`, many programmers have not much time enough to learn `WPF` at the moment (like me) but I don't think I won't learn `WPF`, I'll learn everything possible (`Java, C++, C#, Winforms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET, PHP, All kinds of SQL stuff, iOS programming, LINQ, Regular Expression, ...` all that stuff are making me very excited, I'm a programmer so learning `WPF` is not very a trouble, just don't have time enough right now.

Comment: @VBTheory - if so, you can try an approach which I was using to write very simple animations in WinForms: you have to rewrite your loop to not relate on Thread.Sleep. You measure time between each loop executions and then pass that DELTA to your animation so it knows how many milliseconds have elapsed since previous rendering. Than you can easily count how much the animation should alter in relation to previous frame. I'll dig in into my subversion and find an example of that approach for you, but not at the moment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the program where I make use of heavy animations. Here's how main loop looks like:

```
static void Main() {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Form1 form = new Form1();
    Clock clk = new Clock();
    FPSCounter counter = new FPSCounter();

    form.Show();
    clk.Reset();
    counter.Frequency = clk.Frequency;
    counter.RefreshRate = clk.Frequency / 2;

    double delta, time = 0f;
    long tick;


    while (form.Created) {
        tick = clk.TicksDelta();
        delta = (double)tick / clk.Frequency;
        time += delta;


        form.Update(delta, time);
        Application.DoEvents();

        counter.tick(tick);
        form.Text = counter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Clock class implementation:

```
public class Clock {
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    private static extern bool QueryPerformanceCounter(out long ticks);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    private static extern bool QueryPerformanceFrequency(out long freq);


    private long myTmpFreq;
    private long myTmpCtr;
    private long myDeltaCtr;
    private long myDelta;

    public long Frequency {
        get {
            return myTmpFreq;
        }
    }
    public long Counter {
        get {
            QueryPerformanceCounter(out myTmpCtr);
            return myTmpCtr;
        }
    }

    public void Reset() {
        myDeltaCtr = Counter;
    }
    public long TicksDelta() {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(out myTmpCtr);
        myDelta = myTmpCtr - myDeltaCtr;
        myDeltaCtr = myTmpCtr;
        return myDelta;
    }
    public double Delta() {
        return (double)TicksDelta() / myTmpFreq;
    }


    public Clock() {
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(out myTmpFreq);
    }
}
```

If you make your WinForms application othis way you'll be able to run "real-time" animations and use UI thread as well. Everything will work smooth and nice.

Hope this helps. If you have further questions, please let me know.

**EDIT: FPS Counter implementation**

```
public class FPSCounter {
    private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 25;
    private long[] myTicks = new long[BUFFER_SIZE];
    private int myIdx;


    private decimal myFPS;
    public decimal FPS {
        get {
            return myFPS;
        }
    }

    private long myRefreshRate;
    public long RefreshRate {
        get {
            return myRefreshRate;
        }
        set {
            myRefreshRate = value;
        }
    }

    private long myFreq;

    public long Frequency {
        get { return myFreq; }
        set { myFreq = value; }
    }

    private long myTick;
    public void tick(long tick) {
        myTicks[myIdx++] = tick;
        if (myIdx >= BUFFER_SIZE)
            myIdx = 0;

        myTick += tick;
        if (myTick > myRefreshRate) {
            myTick = 0;
            myFPS = count();
        }
    }

    private decimal count() {
        long sum = 0;
        foreach (long i in myTicks)
            sum += i;

        if (sum == 0)
            return 0;

        return myFreq / (sum / myTicks.Length);
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return String.Format("FPS: {0}", FPS);
    }

}
```

Comment: what about the FPS counter class, where is it?? :/

Comment: You can simply skip this one. I used it to show FPS on window's title bar. But if you really need it I pasted its not-very-good implementation in my post.